# How do I use a variable within a control name? (C#)

Tags: c#, variables, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I want to compress this code into something much more simple, here's basically what code I've written, except I shortened it quite a lot.

```
if (chk1.Checked != true) lab1.Text = rng.Next(1, 7).ToString();
if (chk2.Checked != true) lab2.Text = rng.Next(1, 7).ToString();
```

Instead of many very similar lines, I want a few lines that does this in one go. I tried a 'for' loop, but I don't know how I can use the variable inside of a control name.

```
for (int x = 1; x == 7; x++)
{
    if (chk{x}.Checked != true) lab{x}.Text = rng.Next(1, 7).ToString();
}
```

Obviously {x} doesn't work, but is there anything I can use to make this work?

Comment: `FindControl()`?? which gui are you using? (asp.net, winforms, wpf, silverlight, ...???)

Comment: Look up "C# Collections". Enjoy a coffee (or other suitable beverage) over a tutorial or two and consider this: `new CheckBox[] { chk1, chk2 }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to create 2 equal sized arrays - one to hold the check boxes and one to hold the labels. Then your for loop will look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (checkBoxes[i].Checked == false)
    {
        labels[i].Text = rng.Next(1, 7).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I am feeling this is a WinForms app, I may be wrong, but you need to be clearer in the future.

Each control will have a parent control. For example, all your controls may belong to the same `Panel` control. I will assume this is the case for this example. A `Control` has a `Controls` property which is a collection of child controls, these can be accessed be using the name of the control. So assuming you have your controls named the same as your variables above (named using either the designer, or the `Name` property), then you can do something like this...

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
   Checkbox checkbox = MyParentPanel.Controls["chk" + i] as Checkbox;
   Label label = MyParentPanel.Controls["lab" + i] as Label;
   if(checkbox != null && label != null && !checkbox.Checked)
   {
      label.Text = rng.Next(1, 7).ToString();
   }
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand any of that

Answer (score 0):

a `Dictionary` would fit nicely in a 1:1 scenario where a `CheckBox` is "bound" to a `Label`. Here, the CheckBox acts as the `Key` and the `Label` acts as the value of the `Dictionary`, which can be strongly-typed to ensure you are handling the correct type of data at compile-time.

```
// Declare this at class level
private Dictionary<CheckBox, Label> myControls = new Dictionary<CheckBox, Label>();
// ...

// Dictionary initialization goes in the ctor 
// unless you generate the controls at run-time. 
// If you generate controls, place it after the generation itself
myControls.Add(chk1, lab1);
myControls.Add(chk2, lab2);
// and so on...

// ...    

// When you want to cycle, do this:
foreach(var controlsPair in myControls) {
    // controlsPair is KeyValuePair<CheckBox, Label>
    if(controlsPair.Key.Checked) continue; // SEE (*) BELOW

    controlsPair.Value.Text = rng.Next(1, 7).ToString();
}
```

(*): I always suggest to check for conditions trueness because I find the logic easier to understand when reading the code, but the behavior is exactly the same in the end.

Note: This code should work everywhere (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, etc.)